# Calling method from another class, looked everywhere but cannot solve it

Tags: java, class, methods

I have made the numbers for the Lotto ticket in the Numbers Class and now am trying to run them all and put them into a ticket to display from the Ticket class.

For this I am trying to call the methods. I have got the method in the Ticket class:

```
public void printTicket()
{
    Numbers method = new Numbers();

    method.generateNumbers;
    method.orderNumbers;
    method.printNumbers;
}
```

When compiling I am getting the error 'not a statement' with the first full stop after method.

The method names after `method.` are all correct, but this is the first time I have ever tried calling methods and am stuck!

What could be wrong with my code?

Comment: why are you calling your object method? how bout Numbers num = new Numbers()... then....num.generateNumbers(); for example

Comment: ok, I didn't really know the syntax but I have used what you suggested and it worked! thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void printTicket()
{
 Numbers method = new Numbers();

 method.generateNumbers();
 method.orderNumbers();
 method.printNumbers();
}
```

check parameters if there are any

Comment: this is what I have changed it to and it worked, I just missed out the brackets and it worked! thanks to both of you!